# python: Compare compound primary keys values

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a table with composed primary keys(3 columns)
I'm new to python, I want to get rows where the compound primary key is 123, 'M', 17.

```
row_1 = df[
        (df[pr_keys[0]] == (123, 'M', 17))].iloc[0]
```

I tried also

```
 (123, 'M', 17) but got always syntax error.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @jezrael it does not anwser my question. thank you

Comment: Do you need sql solution?

Comment: Problem is in data missing some sample data, what is `pr_keys` and expected output. So I guess need dupe solution, but maybe  I am wrong. Can you explian more what need?

Comment: @jezrael of course. Thank you for your response. My pr_keys countains the names of columns that are primary keys . For my case (x1, x2, x3) primary key.

Comment: It is tuples, strings? list of strings?

Comment: x1 is int,  x2 is string and x3 int

Comment: OK, so why not compare each column separately like dupe? Not understand.

Comment: row_1 = df[
            (df[pr_keys[0]] == 123 and df [pr_keys[1]]== 'M' and df[pr_keys[2]]== 17)
        ].iloc[0]

Comment: is it what you mean? @jezrael

Comment: super, you are close. Give me a sec.

Comment: Use `row_1 = df[ (df[pr_keys[0]] == 123) & (df [pr_keys[1]] == 'M') & (df[pr_keys[2]]== 17) ].iloc[0]` it return first row if match all 3 conditions